# How can I convert a list into the following format?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a task to find prime factors. In which I want my output in format  like `50="2*5*5"`.
 I have my output in list form

```
FactorList=[2,5,5]
```

How can I convert it into `50="2*5*5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to print FactorList in that format here is some simple code to do that:

```
FactorList=[2,5,5]
print "50=" + str(FactorList[0]) + "*" + str(FactorList[1]) + "*" + str(FactorList[2])
```

This converts each element of FactorList into a string and inserts it into your printed output.

If you want something more general that allows you to input any length list of this kind you might try this:

```
def printInFormat (list):
    value = list[0]
    length = len(list)
    for index in range(1, length):
        value = value * list[index]
    string = str(value) + "="
    for index in range(length-1):
        string = string + str(list[index]) + "*"
    string = string + str(list[length-1])
    return string

FactorList=[2,5,5]

print printInFormat(FactorList)
```

This code follows the same idea, but uses a function to generalize it. I find the length of the list and use a for loop to find the overall value (50) and another for loop to cycle through all of the elements and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Assume s is the list, you can using code like below:

```
s = [2, 5, 5]
print '*'.join(['%s'] * len(s)) % tuple(s)
```